# How to get integrated Console in Visual Studio? (like CLion/IntelliJ)

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, console, visual-studio-2019, clion

Basically I want :
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZsrl.png)
[Not this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIsXF.png)

Any help how to achieve that?